# what's the equilibrium for this special birth-death process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, birth-death-process

This is an example from notes [image]

I have worked out questions from i to iii, no problems with that. But I don't know how to answer question iv, the note says that **"The system reaches an equilibrium for all λ and μ except the trivial case of non-zero arrivals and zero removals"**. But how come it could reach an equilibrium for all λ and μ?

Comment: This seems to be an exact duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862180, which you just deleted. Usually people do that to illegitimately evade downvotes and/or negative comments, but you didn't have either -- why did you do that?

Answer (score 1):

To show that the system reaches an equilibrium distribution for all $\mu, \lambda$ you must show that $P_i(t) \to P_i(\infty)$ for $i$. This has to be done from the set of differential equations for the $P_i$.

Start with $P_0$ and show that it satisfies $P_0' =  \mu(1-P_0) - \lambda P_0$. Find the solution and show that it has a limit.

Then look at $P_1$. It satisfies $P_1'=-(\mu + \lambda)P_1 + \lambda P_0$. Using the limiting behavior of $P_0$, show that $P_1$ has a limit as well.

Then turn this argument into an induction proof.

This will also give you an explicit formula for the limiting distribution. It's a zero-inflated geometric distribution if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Hello, could you explain where did the derivative of $P_0$ come from?